# Why am I never entering the for loop?

Tags: javascript

This is super basic, but I cannot figure it out. I'm never able to enter this for loop. this.state.things is defined, so that is not a problem.

```
  getThingsToRender(){
    let thingsToRender = [];
    console.log(this.state.things)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.things; i++) {
      thingsToRender.push(anything)
    }
    return thingsToRender;
  }
```

Comment: what is `this.state.things`?

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.things`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this.state.things` is an array, you would need to change your for loop to be:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.state.things.length; i++)
```

Alternately, you could do:

```
for(let thing of this.state.things)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're calling the function somewhere else?  You've defined it but haven't called it, at least not in the code shown.

`getThingsToRender()`

You'll also need to adjust your for loop as Anthony posted above to include the `.length` in your `for` declaration